# How Renaming of a java class affects to git status?

Tags: java, git, rename, git-push, git-pull

I am using a remote repository while my team using the same branch and in different packages. 
On my side, I refactored one of the java classes in my package (Right-Click on package explorer > Refactor> Rename). And I did commit ***another change and that change is nothing related to the refactored one***.

When the code is committed to the remote repository, it gives compilation errors to others once it gets a pull. But from my side no errors or build break issues.

Can someone explain;

1. What is the reason behind that?
2. How to avoid compilation errors in a situation like that?

Comment: Was the renamed file displayed as untracked file and you forgot to include it in  commit?

Comment: When I check `git status` rename was already in green colour.

Comment: Worth updating the question with what exactly was the compilation error with some code snippets

Answer (score 1):

When you have refactored a class file, below two new changes would have been created:

1. Delete change of class file with old name.
2. new file with new class file name would be created.

Please commit both the changes and your issue should be resolved.